Using Recommendation Engine to recommend a movie for two users
I'm using torch and Fastai to train data and come up with user weights vs item weights. With the trained data, what is the best way to recommend a movie to a pair of users using a combination of both user weights? Is it as simple as taking the average of each of the n parameter weights for the pair of users and then using those weights and Cosine Similarity function to find the best item? I'm a noobie to machine learning and data science so apologies if it is a silly question.
movie_factors = learn.model.i_weight.weight
user_factors = learn.model.u_weight.weight

#Choosing two random users
user1_factors = user_factors[43].data.cpu().numpy()
user2_factors = user_factors[54].data.cpu().numpy()

# Calculate the average of user1_factors and user2_factors
avg_u_factors = torch.from_numpy(np.array((user1_factors + user2_factors) / 2)).to(movie_factors.device)

distances = nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=1)(movie_factors, avg_u_factors)
idx = distances.argsort(descending=True)[1]
dls.classes['title'][idx]

